# Android studio no module

Tags: android-studio

So at University I started to create an app with android studio. Now I want to finish it at home, so i copied all the files on my USB stick and opend the project from it at home. But as i want to run it i get the message: 'module not specified'.

And i cant select a module as the only thing it says is 'no module'

[Edit configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPWKL.png)

I can not import my project as it is already imported.

How can i simply add 'another' module?

Answer (score -1):

You have to attach "Gradle" on the project, somehow it hasn't been recognized by your PC, since i guess you just have installed at your laptop Android Studio.

Comment: What do you mean "attach Gradle on the project"? How is this done (teaspoon please). I get the no-module error after updating Gradle to 4.10.1 (from 4.4). In the project structure I have set this gradle version and the corresponding wrapper